# WPF datagrid row header binding - Observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

I have built a datagrid using datatable and the results are displayed correctly. 
Now I intend to add ROWHEADERs to the datagrid. I populated an `observable collection<string>`and in the `XAML`, I use that as row header data template path. Still, it is not showing up. Can somebody advice where the issue is?

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Rownameheaders { get; set; } //in the main .cs

//xaml.cs
public void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WF_CRM_RPluginModel model = DataContext as WF_CRM_RPluginModel;
    var hello1 =  new ObservableCollection<String>();

    for(int i=0; i< model.prodwells.Count;i++)
    {
        hello1.Add(model.prodwells[i]);
    }

    model.Rownameheaders = hello1;

    List<double[]> list = new List<double[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.RowFijtable; i++)
    {
        double[] rowdata = new double[model.ColFijtable];
        for (int j = 0; j < model.ColFijtable; j++)
        {
            rowdata[j] = model.TauTable[i, j];
        }

        list.Add(rowdata);
    }

    DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);

    dataGridView1.ItemsSource = table.AsDataView();  
}

private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<double[]> list)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    WF_CRM_RPluginModel model = DataContext as WF_CRM_RPluginModel;
    // Get max columns.
    int columns = 0;
    foreach (var array in list)
    {
        if (array.Length > columns)
        {
            columns = array.Length;
        }
    }

    // Add columns.
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        // Provide default column name & data type
        table.Columns.Add(model.injwells[i], typeof(double));
    }

    // Add rows.
    foreach (var array in list)
    {
        // assign each array element to the appropriate column
        var row = table.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
            row.SetField(i, array[i]);

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridView1" Loaded="Form1_load" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"                                          AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" CanUserSortColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Rownameheaders}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate> 
</DataGrid>
```

This is the result I get but with no row headers...

[image]

Comment: Your binding looks for a visual ancestor of type `DataGridRow`, and if it finds one, it binds to `DataGridRow.Rownameheaders`. But `DataGridRow` has no property by that name. Try `Path=DataContext.Rownameheaders[0]` -- I think that'll get you the first rowname header. Your next problem is how to make it get the right item from that collection for each row. Some kind of multi value converter, I guess, that binds to Rownameheaders and something that it would get an index from.

Comment: Maybe your best bet would be to add a RowHeader column to your DataTable and bind to that. Or use a collection of a POCO class rather than a DataTable, and give the POCO class a property that'll be used as the row header.

Comment: Thanks @EdPlunkett! I ended up adding a new column. Please see the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a new column with values and setting the column location to 0 in the datatable. Below is the updated code:

```
private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<double[]> list)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    WF_CRM_RPluginModel model = DataContext as WF_CRM_RPluginModel;
    // Get max columns.
    int columns = 0;
    foreach (var array in list)
    {
        if (array.Length > columns)
        {
            columns = array.Length;
        }
    }

   // Add columns.
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        // Provide default column name & data type
        table.Columns.Add(model.injwells[i], typeof(double));

    }

    // Add rows.
    foreach (var array in list)
    {
        // assign each array element to the appropriate column
        var row = table.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
            row.SetField(i, array[i]);
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //ADDED below part
    DataColumn newCol = new DataColumn("Prod Name", typeof(string));
    newCol.AllowDBNull = true;
    table.Columns.Add(newCol);
    newCol.SetOrdinal(0);
    int m = 0;
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        row["Prod Name"] = model.prodwells[m];
        m = m + 1;
    }

    return table;
}
```

hope it helps others too!